# Ошибка при изменении Lable

Tags: ios, swift

Я хочу менять текст своего `Lable` на другой делаю, я это при помощи `GeneratedNameLable.text = "BUTTON"`, но компилятор мне говорит что код неверный:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

У вас `GeneratedNameLable` как NSTextField, поменять текст можно как:

```
self.GeneratedNameLable.stringValue = "\(result.sum)"
```

---

Либо используйте [`UILabel`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/text), и тогда ваш код не будет показывать ошибку.

Answer (score 1):

Вы его объявили не `UITextField` (класс iOS), а `NSTextField` (класс OSX).